# Angular How to build a directive template when properties via web service are needed

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Basically i need to build a control, but i need details from a web service before i can build the html. What is the proper way to do this.

Here is what i have at the moment, but i am not sure if this is correct or not, or whether i should be using a controller, should the WebService.get() method be in the link method of the directive?

Advice/input much appreciated

```
App.directive('myDirective', ['WebService', '$compile', function (WebService, $compile) {
    'use strict';

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            // get my data from the server
            WebService.get().then(function(columns) {

                var html = '';

                // add some html here
                // ....

                // loop through some server data
                for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
                    html += '<td>' + columns.name + '</td>;
                }

                // build rest of html here
                // ....

                // compile the html for angular use
                html = $compile(html)(scope);

                // set element html
                element.html(html);

            });

        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: You should put a ng-repeat inside the template reading some array from the directive scope.

Comment: ok, but is that good from a performance point of view? ng-repeat will watch my scope values (eg. $scope.columns), but these will never change.  Also should the WebService.get() be within the link function?

Comment: Given that It will never chance, then the watch will be no problem. You can pass values from outside or just call the WebService from inside the directive.